# Portfolio Theory - Maximizing Expected Utility Function

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, utility-theory

I am trying to implement a portfolio selection tool based on utility functions. So, I should maximize the expected utility of a given utility function:
$$
\begin{align}
&\max_{w}\ E[u(W_0(1+w^TR))]\\\\
& s.t.\\
&w^Te = 1, \ e^T=[1,...,1]
\end{align}
$$
Using the quadratic utility function we get:
\begin{align}
&E[u(W_0(1+w^TR))] = u(W_0) + W_0\mu_p(1-bW_0)-\frac{b}{2}W_0^2(\sigma_p^2 + \mu_p^2)\\\\
&\mu_p \ \text{is the portfolio mean and} \ \sigma_p \ \text{is the portfolio 
 standard deviation}
\end{align}

I already implemented this, but I get different weights for different initial wealth values, is this normal? One thing that I find odd is that for a large enough initial wealth, the model doesn't tend to the minimum variance portfolio as risk aversion goes up.

Comment: Quadratic utility is known to have some limitations. For ex "the quadratic utility function exhibits increasing absolute risk aversion. Thus, the quadratic function is consistent with investors who reduce the nominal amount invested in risky assets as their wealth increases" https://www.d42.com/portfolio/analysis/quadratic-utility

Comment: Yes, it is normal for quadratic utility to produce different results given different levels of initial wealth.